# List of CORS domains for Office Online - Custom functions not loading

Tags: office-js

We are continuing to hit validation issues caused by our `functions.json` not loading due to a CORS issue, even though it works for us with every browser supported by Excel Online.

Support has been mostly unhelpful, sending us here and being unable to supply us with a list of CORS origins to whitelist on our server.

So far we have been able to deduce the following origins:

- https://auc-excel.officeapps.live.com
- https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com

But even with these whitelisted domains, this is what the Microsoft testing team continues to send us:

[image: internal team error report]

We absolutely cannot reproduce the issue. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You may find some information here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations. Do you still hit the issue after following the suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - my CDN was caching the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header response regardless of the origin being sent in the request.

Fixed it by duplicating my CORS rules in the CDN as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors#one-regular-expression-with-all-valid-origins

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting domains is not enough to make cross origin calls in the add-in. There are several ways to bridge the gap:

1. One way to overcome same-origin policy limitations is to use JSONP to provide a proxy for the web service. See [Use JSONP for anonymous access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations#use-jsonp-for-anonymous-access) for more information.
2. Configure CORS by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response as described [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).
3. Another way to address same-origin policy limitations is to provide server-side code that uses [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) flows to enable one domain to get authorized access to resources hosted on another.